# Can I set custom metrics with Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a basic yet complicated question. I'm trying to create a custom metric to count number of new memberships. Can I do it with Google Tag Manager?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, just go to "More Settings" of your tag, and then "Custom Metrics". An alternative to CMs is to capture memberships as a goal, either through an event or a funnel.

Answer (score 1):

To create a custom metric with total new memberships:

Create a custom metric, with a scope of hit, and formatting type of integer. Make a note of what index this custom metric is (e.g. 1).

Create an event in Google Tag Manager, which triggers on the creation of a new account. In settings for the event, go to More Settings -> Custom Metrics ->  and click ADD CUSTOM METRIC.

In index, insert the index value given by Google Analytics when you set up the custom dimension (in this case 1), and set the metric value to 1. This would allow for you to aggregate in custom dimension 1, the total number of new memberships.

Its probably more relevant to set this up as a goal however, as this will give you conversion rates, and all the other added benefits.